# Calling external javascript from localhost and WAMP

Tags: javascript, localhost, wamp

I'm learning how to build a webpage and have been practicing using WAMP.  I've hit a problem I don't understand.  If I try this example from my browser (going there directly from the address bar) http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_externalexample  It works fine.

But if I cut and paste the sample source code into a file on my computer and try to access it via localhost, nothing happens.

What am I missing or doing wrong?  - Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need the 'myscript.js' file in the same folder, to use that script. Copy it to local file or link to the full url (http://www.w3schools.com/js/myScript.js)

Btw you can usually diagnose problems like this with Firebug or Chrome Developer tools, they should give a warning in the console about missing/404 requests.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the js file. you need to get the js file in the same folder and write a `<script src="/myscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` and then try working with your page again.